# Proof that all rational Cauchy sequences converge to real

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, real-numbers, cauchy-sequences

I'm trying to understand the construction of the real numbers using Cauchy sequences. I get that not all rational Cauchy sequences converge to a rational number, however, how do we know that the number they do converge to is real? Is there something I'm missing or do you need to prove that all rational Cauchy sequences converge to a real?

Comment: According to one definition of the real numbers, they are precisely the numbers to which rational Cauchy sequences converge. There are a few things to check in this definition: that cauchy sequences  of real numbers converge to real numbers and that the real numbers are an ordered field. All of this is to say that it is impossible to prove that Cauchy sequences converge to real numbers without first deciding how you will define the real numbers, since one possible definition of the real numbers subsumes that proof.

Comment: The real numbers are defined to be equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences.  So it's actually true by definition, there's nothing to prove.

Comment: @GregoryGrant that is, of course, *one* way to define the real numbers.  Another way is via Dedekind cuts.  Yet another way is a purely axiomatic characterization (as a complete ordered field, which is unique up to isomorphism).  Without knowing which definition the OP is using I don't see how this question is answerable.